# How to find out more about installed app?

Tags: .net

On a customer's computer I noticed a newish app installed.  I want to do a bit of snooping on this app to find out what language it's been written in and what its design is.

Just by looking at the files in the App's folder, how could I determine any of the following:

- version of .NET targetted
- whether WPF used
- whether Silverlight used
- any other interesting features

Answer (score 0):

You can tell a fair bit about an application by using such tools as [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) (free) or [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) (costs)

You can load the main executable with it and from the referenced dlls you'll be able to work out the info you are looking for.

These tools can be used to view the source, or the decompiled version of the source anyway...if they have not been obfuscated